# Idiomatically testing when.js promises with Jasmine

Tags: jasmine, promise, when-js

I'm writing some Jasmine unit tests for code that returns `when.js` promises. I keep finding myself writing code like this:

```
doMyThing().then(function(x) {
  expect(x).toEqual(42);
  done();
}).otherwise(function() {
  expect(true).toBe(false);
  done();
});
```

The only way to catch the exception is with the `otherwise()` function (it's an older version of [when.js](https://github.com/cujojs/when/blob/master/docs/api.md)), and then there doesn't seem to be a Jasmine (2.0) function to say "failure detected" - hence the kludgy "`expect(true).toBe(false)`".

Is there a more idiomatic way of doing this?

Comment: can't you simply do `}).otherwise(done);`, and the error automatically gets passed to the `done` method

Comment: No - Jasmine doesn't do anything with arguments passed to `done()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking a bit more closely at the documentation and realising that we're using Jasmine 2.3, I see we can make use of the `fail()` function, which massively simplifies things. The example in the question becomes:

```
doMyThing().then(function(x) {
  expect(x).toEqual(42);
}).otherwise(fail).then(done);
```

If `doMyThing()` throws an exception, that Error gets passed to `fail()` which prints a stack trace.

This `.otherwise(fail).then(done);` turns out to be a pretty convenient idiom.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider a testing library with promises support like Mocha, or using a helper like jasmine-as-promised which gives you this syntax. This would let you do something along the lines of:

```
// notice the return, and _not_ passing `done` as an argument to `it`:
return doMyThing().then(function(x) {
  expect(x).toEqual(42);
});
```

Basically, the return value is checked to be a promise and if it is the test framework checks if the promise rejected and treats that as a failure.

Comment: Ok, that's helpful to know. Are you implicitly saying there's no way to do anything nicer without a helper library like that?

Comment: You can write short helpers, but I'd just use the modern approach rather than reinvent wheels. Then again I'd probably write tests with babel and use async/await which would make for even nicer syntax.

Comment: Yeah. Well there's always a better way of doing whatever we're doing :) Anyway it's not my codebase, so I'm certainly not making any big changes like that.